# Abstract method in object in Pascal

Tags: oop, binary-tree, pascal

I have been working on AVL-tree unit where user can specify what he wants to have inside of the tree. I'm using objects for this purpose. In my unit I defined parent Object called Node and pointer to this object is PTNode. In this object I have 3 attributes which are Balance:integer;Left,Right:PTNode for sons of the node, and 1 method:Function Is_Greater(Node1:PTNode):integer which is virtual and abstract. And it is left up to user to define this function(I don't know whether it will be char or integer etc).

I was trying to test this unit and I came across one problem. I created child object of my object Node called Object1=Object(Node) and added one attribute X:integer and I want to define the Function Is_Greater. Here is the declaration and part of code:

Unit

```
Unit Tree;
interface
type PTNode=^Node;  
  Node=object
     Left,Right:PTNode;    
     Balance:integer;
     Function Is_Greater(Node1:PTNode):integer; virtual; abstract;
   end;
```

after this I define my function in my unit which are not that relevant to my problem.

This is my test program:

```
Program Test;
 uses Tree;
 Type PTObject=^Object1;
      Object1=object(Node)
         X:integer;
         Function Is_Greater(Node1:PTNode):integer; virtual;
       end;
  Function Object1.Is_Greater(Node1:PTNode):integer;
    begin
      if X>Node1^.X then Is_Greater:=1
       else if X<Node1^.X then Is_Greater:=-1
         else Is_Greater:=0;
     end;
```

and it gives me error saying that X is not part of Object Node. But when I try to set Node1:PTObject then it gives me error that my function doesn't match its parent. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abstract function in Pascal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416605/abstract-function-in-pascal)

Answer (score 1):

All object variables are pointers. So you don't need a `PTObject` and `PTNode` types. You can simply pass variables of type `Node` and `Object1` around.

Your basic `Node` defines a an abstract method expecting a parameter `Node1:PTNode`. As I said before you can change it to `Function Is_Greater(Node1: Node):integer; virtual; abstract`. `Node` has no member called `X`. You need to cast `Node1` to `Object1` in order to access `X`.

This looks like this:

```
Program Test;
 uses Tree;
   Object1=object(Node)
     X:integer;
     Function Is_Greater(Node1:Node):integer; override; // don't use virtual here!
   end;

Function Object1.Is_Greater(Node1:Node):integer;
var 
  OtherObject1: Objetc1;
begin
  // the next line can crash when there are objects in the tree 
  // which are not of type object1!
  OtherObject1 := Node1 as Object1; 
  if X>OtherObject1 .X then Is_Greater:=1
   else if X<OtherObject1.X then Is_Greater:=-1
     else Is_Greater:=0;
 end;
```